# Is there a hoist-free version of BOOST_FOREACH?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, macros, foreach

I'm aware of the "hoisting" [pitfall](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html) of BOOST_FOREACH where it caches the end iterator. However it seems that:

1. Modifying sequences mid loop is fairly common (especially push_back)
2. It wouldn't be hard to provide a version of BOOST_FOREACH that was didn't hoist so was immune to modification problems.

Clearly people often just write the loop by hand in these cases, but my question is this:

- Does such a version exist? something like BOOST_FOREACH_NOHOIST or some such.

I've thus far been unable to find one.

*Note:* edited in response to Steve Jessop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Modifying sequences mid loop is fairly common"

Avoiding the hoist would not make the macro immune to modification problems, since BOOST_FOREACH is also using a moving iterator under the covers that might be invalidated by `push_back` (for example you're using a vector and it reallocates) or other structural modifications. Not much use getting a new, valid `end` iterator if the thing you're comparing to it isn't valid any more.

It seems reasonable to me to provide something that *obviously* has problems with structural modifications. The pitfall says, "If doing so could cause iterators to become invalid, don't do it. Use a regular for loop instead.", without specifying *which* iterators need to remain valid. Use a for loop if your operations might break *any* iterator.

Providing something that *sometimes* has problems, depending on the nature of the modifications, means that the macro would have to document what modifications are OK and what aren't (if only by describing the hidden iterator and saying, "don't invalidate that, but you can invalidate other iterators"), which starts to become an awkward API. From a sample of one user, 100% assumed it would be immune, so I'm not sure it's a very intuitive interface.

That said, I think you're right that BOOST_FOREACH could easily guarantee that it only holds (1) the end iterator, plus (2) an iterator pointing at the current iterand. So if you had a hoist-free version, with (2) but not (1), then all you'd need to do is ensure you don't invalidate the current iterator. I don't think it exists, though, the author of that pitfall seems to consider the end iterator to be all part of the danger of invalidation, rather than trying to separate out different kinds of invalidation. I think `BOOST_FOREACH` was intended as an improved syntax for `std::for_each` over a Boost.Range, and meets that goal. You could always suggest to the relevant Boost people that it could be more than that.

Comment: "Providing something that sometimes has problems" -- I might agree accept that stl containers in general have this issue. Perhaps I should drop "modification-safe" in the title.

Comment: @Catskul: sure, it's the same for any standard algorithm except that they all explicitly hoist since you pass the end iterator as a parameter, so the desire for a nohoist version never arises. You should follow the same rules as BOOST_FOREACH - you don't know exactly what iterator values exist, especially for iterators that are better than InputIterator, so don't invalidate anything during the algorithm. If you want to invalidate iterators, either work very carefully through the standard to find the guarantees you need or else don't use an algorithm that hides the iterators, write a loop...